# Adding 2 different actions to a single IBAction - Random Choice

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

At the moment I have an `IBAction` linked to go to `showLeaderboard`, user presses, no problem.

```
-(IBAction)RandomView {

[[GameManager sharedGameManager] showLeaderboard:self];

}
```

However, how (if at all possible) can I make it so that it is at random that it may go to a different screen maybe every other press or something like that, so for example;

```
 -(IBAction)RandomView {

    [[GameManager sharedGameManager] showLeaderboard:self];
```

OR

```
showmy2ndView;

    }
```

Is that possible or would it be too complex to integrate?

Comment: sorry, your question is not clear, do you want that if the user press for a long time, your button it has another action?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the simplest way to choose randomly between two possibilities:

```
if (arc4random() % 2 == 0) {
    // do one thing
} else {
    // do another thing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a random generator, such as:

```
int randomVar = arc4Random()%1
```

Then perform a switch statement upon the randomVar, and in the different cases I would use the 'self performSegueWithIdentifier:' method.